forwarding emails from gmail to discord using zapier (content wont show)
I am trying to make a automation where all my gmails gets forwarded into my discord channel with other people, my current setup shows like this in discord:
"New email received!
From:
Subject:
Message:"
The email is forwarded, however its not able to bring in the data. I think im using the wrong id or class to bring it in but dont know or cant find a way to get in this data. In the screenshot you can see my zapier setup. Gmail is setup so the trigger should be fine, but im receiving errors in my {{}} data.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/MBYX4kNp.png)
FYI its also programmed in JSON, and im very new to programming.
All help is appreciated.
Ive tried several things to find out the correct data inputs, even asked chatGPT, thats how desperate i am:)

Rather than use the Webhook action, Discord supports the action to post directly in a channel:

You can use that to share your email in a Discord channel.
